# Javascript function to get a convert a number to X number of digits only

Tags: javascript

I want to use a javascript function which gets a real number, and makes the whole number X digits, (except if the integer part is larger).

I will give you some examples.
Suppose the function I am looking for is f(a,b) where a is the number we have, and b is the digits we want to be converted:

```
f(1.23456,5)    =>1.2345
f(1.23456,6)    =>1.23456
f(1.23456,7)    =>1.234560
f(123.45,5)     =>123.45
f(12345.678,5)  =>12345
f(1234567.89,5) =>1234567
```

Is there any function which does that?

The closer function to this I guess is `Number(N).toFixed(X)`, which fixes only the right part a real number to X digits, but not the whole number..

Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Numbers have a function that does that, [toPercision](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision) though note that it will round to the last digit

Comment: @PatrickEvans: I think you should add this as an answer, especially given the amount of inferior or wrong answers that are being posted.

Comment: Yea i was just about to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[toPrecision](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision) does mostly what you want, the only difference is that it rounds to the last digit:

```
var n = 1.23456;
console.log( n.toPrecision(5) ); //outputs 1.2346
n = 1234.56;
console.log( n.toPrecision(4) ); //outputs 1235
```

Do not know if there is a way to prevent the rounding, if rounding is unwanted... will update answer if i can find a way or someone graciously mentions a way to prevent the rounding without having to do the string manipulations.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
function x(s, n){
    s = s.toString();
    var sp = s.split(".");
    if( sp[0].length >= n || sp.length == 1  ) return parseFloat(sp[0]);
    return parseFloat( sp[0] + "." + sp[1].substring(0, n - sp[0].length) );
}

console.log(x(2342342.23, 4))// Output 2342342
console.log(x(2342342.23, 8))// Output 2342342.2
console.log(x(2342342.23, 9)) // Output 2342342.23
console.log(x(2342342.23, 15)) // Output 2342342.23
```

Comment: It needs to add trailing `0`'s if the param is longer than the numbers. That final case would be `23423242.2300000`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
function f(number, N) { 
    var intPart = number.toFixed(0),
        decPartLen = N - intPart.length;
    return decPartLen > 0 ? number.toFixed(decPartLen) : intPart;
}
```

The only difference is that the number will be rounded. But it seems more correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
function f(num, chars) {
    var numOfFloats = chars - String(Math.floor(num)).length;
    if (numOfFloats > 0) {
        return new Number(num).toFixed(numOfFloats);
    } else {
        return Math.floor(num);
    }
}
```

jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/56Lk4/

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this

```
function f(numb, dec) {
    var sub  = Math.floor(numb % 10),
        mult = Math.pow(10, (dec-sub));
    return (sub > dec) ? parseInt(numb, 10) : parseInt(numb*mult, 10) / mult;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ReAq4/1/)

It doesn't add trailing zeros after the decimal point, as that's not possible with numbers, you'd have to convert the numbers to strings, which sort of defeats the purpose of this, but if you really want strings you can do

```
function f(numb, dec) {
    var sub  = Math.floor(numb % 10),
        mult = Math.pow(10, (dec-sub));

    if (sub > dec) return parseInt(numb, 10).toString();
    var n = (parseInt(numb*mult, 10) / mult).toString();
    while (n.replace('.','').length < dec) {n = n+'0';}

    return n;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ReAq4/3/)

Answer (score 1):

This function is short and does just what you want.

javascript:

```
function truncate(number, truncateTo)
{alert(number.substring(0, truncateTo));}
```

HTML (button i made if you want to try it out):

```
<button onclick="truncate('1234', 2)">Truncate</button>
```